# Sync two asynchronous API call with RxJava

Tags: java, rx-java

In what way can we sync two asynchronous calls using RxJava? In the example below, the method `contentService.listContents` which is a API call must first finish before the `processSchema` method to take place for each schema.

```
schemaService.listSchema()
    .toObservable()
    .flatMapIterable(schemas -> {
        schemas.forEach(schema -> {
            // async call
            contentService.listContents(schema.getName()).subscribe(contents -> {
                   doSomethingWithThe(contents); 
            });
        });
        // contentService.listContents` must complete first before 
        // processSchema should be called for each schema
        return schemas;
    }).subscribe(schema -> { processSchema(schema); }, 
                 error -> { Console.error(error.getMessage()); });
```

The problem with the code above the `processSchema` would not wait for the `contentService.listContents` since it is async not not synchronized with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `flatMap` to process the `schemas` and since it is a list, you have to unroll it and `flatMap` again:

```java
schemaService.listSchema()
.toObservable()
.flatMap(schemas -> 
     Observable.fromIterable(schemas)
     .flatMap(schema -> 
         contentService.listContents(schema.getName())
         .doOnNext(contents -> doSomethingWith(contents))
     )
     // probably you don't care about the inner contents
     .ignoreElements()
     // andThen will switch to this only when the sequence above completes
     .andThen(Observable.just(schemas))
)
.subscribe(
    schema -> processSchema(schema), 
    error -> Console.error(error.getMessage())
);
```

Note that you haven't defined the return types of the service calls so you may have to use `flatMapSingle` and `doOnSuccess` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `flatMap`.

From the [`docs`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#continuations)

> **Continuations**
>
> Sometimes, when an item has become available, one would
>   like to perform some dependent computations on it. This is sometimes
>   called continuations and, depending on what should happen and what
>   types are involved, may involve various operators to accomplish.
>
> **Dependent**
>
> The most typical scenario is to given a value, invoke
>   another service, await and continue with its result:

```
service.apiCall()
.flatMap(value -> service.anotherApiCall(value))
.flatMap(next -> service.finalCall(next))
```

> It is often the case also that later sequences would require values
>   from earlier mappings. This can be achieved by moving the outer
>   flatMap into the inner parts of the previous flatMap for example:

```
service.apiCall()
.flatMap(value ->
    service.anotherApiCall(value)
    .flatMap(next -> service.finalCallBoth(value, next))
)
```

Comment: Note that the "value" in my case is an Iterable so your code does not show that